# Charles Proxy not capturing localhost traffic when using Safari on MAC

Tags: proxy, safari, localhost, charles-proxy

When using Safari on MAC, Charles proxy is not capturing the localhost traffic.

Using Opera, Chrome and Firefox all works as expected and captures all the localhost traffic.

I have researched this issue extensively but to no avail. I have tried using ...

http://localhost.charlesproxy.com, local ip address, machine name etc and several other suggestions but nothing seems to work

Comment: Are you running a local HTTP server on the port you are trying to reach? I am, and I also cannot track anything from Safari on localhost (http://localhost:8000) on Charles 3.11.5 with Mac High Sierra 10.13.2. It works on all other browsers and my certificate is set to Always Trust. So, perhaps this is a bug?

Comment: I am running Charles 4.2.1 and Mac High Sierra 10.13.2. But as you say this might be a bug in Safari if all the other browsers work OK? Be good to hear anyone else's thoughts.

Comment: Maybe your Safari is not using the system's proxy, though it should (something similar happened to me with Windows). I would suggest you to ensure Safari is using the Charles Proxy (probably you'll find the proxy settings under some "Preferences" or "Configuration" menu on Safari (I'm sorry, I've never used Safari). If this works, then consider using a plugin (or equivalent) to switch between proxy configurations (such as Chrome's SwitchySharp extension).

Comment: I am able to record other traffic using Safari, I just can't record localhost traffic. Why should it disregard localhost traffic? I am unable to change much in the settings as I don't have Admin rights but not sure if there is any need for me to do so?

Answer (score 7):

The following worked for me with Safari 12.0 in Mojave:

1. In Charles, in the *Recording Settings*, under *Include*, I added `http://localhost.:8080/`. Note the `.` (dot) after `localhost`, and of course replace `8080` with whatever port matters to you.
2. In Safari, I used the `http://localhost.:8080/` to connect to my app running locally.

It seems that by default either Safari or a library that Safari uses doesn't use the proxy for `localhost`. I would prefer to find a way to setup Safari or macOS so `localhost` wasn't excluded, but haven't found one.

Also see [Localhost traffic doesn't appear in Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/localhost-traffic-doesnt-appear-in-charles/) from the Charles FAQ.